# Represent percentage increase in equation (and plot it)

Tags: graphing-functions, percentages

How could i write a function to represent the increase by a certain percentage?
e.g.
given an amount **x**, and given an increase percentage (10% ), i want as a result [x + (x*10/100)] then at the next step is the new value + 10% of the new value and so on..

does this need differential equation?

How can I plot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note in your example of $x + x\frac{10\%}{100\%}$ that it can be simplified to $x(1 + 0.1) = (1.1)x$. That is, instead of "adding 10% to $x$", this can be thought of as "multiplying $x$ by $1.1$".

More generally, if you want to increase by $p\%$, then you calculate
$$r = 1 + \frac{p\%}{100\%} = 1+(0.01)p$$
And the increase operation is $x \mapsto rx$.

Now you talk about doing this in *steps*. So you have some starting value $x_0$, then you calculate the next values $$\begin{align}x_1 &= rx_0\\x_2 &= rx_1 = r(rx_0) = r^2x_0\\x_3 &= rx_2 = r(r^2x_0) = r^3x_0\\&\ \ \vdots\\x_n &= r^nx_0\end{align}$$

And that is your formula. The result of the $n$-th increase is $r^n x_0$.

Comment: thank you, it was so simple but i was so far.
And how would a plot look like?

Comment: It's an exponential function. You are only doing discrete steps on it, but obviously you can treat $n$ as a real number instead of integer if you are interested in "partial steps". Depending on your purposes for this, that concept can be perfectly sensible, or perfect nonsense. [You can see an example here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zjjgyow8rc) for $x_0 = 1, r = 1.1$.